# How to generalize this calculation with a pandas DataFrame to any number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a file with some data that looks like

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
```

I can process this data and do math on it just fine:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def main():
    if(len(sys.argv) != 2):
        print "Takes one filename as argument"
        sys.exit()

    file_name = sys.argv[1]

    data = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=" ", header=None)
    data.columns = ["timestep", "mux", "muy", "muz"]

    t = data["timestep"].count()

    c = np.zeros(t)

    for i in range(0,t):
        for j in range(0,i+1):
            c[i-j] += data["mux"][i-j] * data["mux"][i]
            c[i-j] += data["muy"][i-j] * data["muy"][i] 
            c[i-j] += data["muz"][i-j] * data["muz"][i]

    for i in range(t):
        print c[i]/(t-i)
```

The expected result for my sample input above is

```
42.5
62.0
84.5
110.0
```

This math is finding the *time correlation function* for my data, which is the time-average of all permutations of the pairs of products in each column.
I would like to generalize this program to

- work on `n` number of columns (in the i/j loop for example), and
- be able to read in the column names from the file, so as to not have them hard-coded in

Which `numpy` or `pandas` methods can I use to accomplish this?

Comment: Thank you for the relevant code sample, but could you provide a brief description of the formula you're trying to apply along with the expected output for the example data provided?

Comment: If the file does not have the column names or anything that can be interpreted as column names, pandas cannot determine the column names. Also as @vealkind says, if you can briefly describe the math formula, may be someone can help.

Comment: @vealkind changes have been added, please let me know if anything else is missing

Comment: @HarvIpan to have the column names in the file, do I use the field Name=infer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reduce it to one loop, as we would make use of array-slicing and use `sum` ufunc to operate along the rows of the dataframe and thus in the process make it generic to cover any number of columns, like so -

```
a = data.values
t = data["timestep"].count()
c = np.zeros(t)
for i in range(t):
    c[:i+1] += (a[:i+1,1:]*a[i,1:]).sum(axis=1)
```

**Explanation**

1) `a[:i+1,1:]` is the slice of all rows until the `i+1`-th row and all columns starting from the second column, i.e `mux`, `muy` and so on.

2) Similarly, for `[i,1:]`, that's the `i-th` row and all columns from second column onwards.

To keep it "pandas-way", simply replace `a[` with `data.iloc[`.

Comment: sorry if I'm being a bother, but could you explain how the slices work for the array indices? I'm not familiar with them and looking them up hasn't clarified what you're doing with them here unfortunately

Comment: @Luciano Added some explanation.